# String from Class instead off a TextView

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a Push Notification to get random quotes every day. I can only figure out how to get the text from the "textViewNextQuote", but thats not what I want! I want random from the class  "displayQuote()" directly NOT from the textView "textViewNextQuote". How do I rewrite the script?

```
    editTextTitle = findViewById(R.id.textTitle);
    editTextMessage = findViewById(R.id.textViewNextQuote); //not what I want, I want directly from displayQuote

    buttonChannel1 = findViewById(R.id.button_channel1);
    mNotificationHelper = new NotificationHelper(this);

    buttonChannel1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            sendOnChannel1(
                    editTextTitle.getText().toString(),
                    editTextMessage.getText().toString());
        }
    });
```

-

```
public void sendOnChannel1(String title, String message){
        NotificationCompat.Builder nb = mNotificationHelper.getChannel1Notification(title, message);
        mNotificationHelper.getManager().notify(1, nb.build());
    }
```

and this class:

```
 public void displayQuote(){
        //random number between 1 and 10 (both inclusive)
            int randNum = random.nextInt((164+1) -1) + 1;
            String randQuote = "";

        switch (randNum){
            case 1 :
                randQuote = getString(R.string.quote1);
                break;
            case 2 :
                randQuote = getString(R.string.quote2);
                break;
            case 3 :
                randQuote = getString(R.string.quote3);
                break;
    }
    textQuot.setText(randQuote);
```

Answer (score 1):

Return `randQuote` from `displayQuote()`

```
public String displayQuote() {
   //...
   return randQuote;
}
```

And call the method `displayQuote()`

Comment: I changed it to public string and added "return randQuote" also used "editTextMessage = displayQuote();" but I get "incompatible type" error.

Comment: Because you need to set the string to TextView, They have different data types. to set the data  `editTextMessage.setText(displayQuote())`